# How to make if condition of css height in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, toggle

I have a Text which when I click on it should toggle. It works if I don't have style condition on it but how can I accomplish this with style.

HTML CODE

```
    <section class="discription-list">
           <div class="description-title">
             <h3 class="button1">Description</h3>
             <h3 class="button2">Product Detail</h3>
             <h3 class="button3">Shipping Info</h3>
           </div>


           <div class="toggle-list"></div>
        </section>
```

CSS CODE

```
.toggle-list{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var btnt = document.querySelector('.description-title');
      btnt.addEventListener('click', toggleClick);

           function toggleClick(e) {
            var div = document.querySelector('.toggle-list');

              if (e.target === document.querySelector('.button1') && div.style.height === '0px') {
                var tag1 = '<div id="wrapper1" class="open1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur ante eget lorem varius, ut lacinia leo finibus. Nam commodo luctus odio ac consectetur. Donec vel magna nec augue condimentum condimentum ut a neque. Mauris leo sem, tincidunt ac vulputate eget, ullamcorper vitae velit. Morbi a sem laoreet tellus bibendum iaculis non eu mauris. Nam ut interdum massa, ac lacinia velit. Praesent imperdiet fringilla interdum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur ante eget lorem varius, ut lacinia leo finibus. Nam commodo luctus odio ac consectetur. Donec vel magna nec augue condimentum condimentum ut a neque. Mauris leo sem, tincidunt ac vulputate eget, ullamcorper vitae velit. Morbi a sem laoreet tellus bibendum iaculis non eu mauris. Nam ut interdum massa, ac lacinia velit. Praesent imperdiet fringilla interdum.</p></div>';
                    div.innerHTML = tag1;
                    div.style.height = '160px';
              }else if (e.target === document.querySelector('.button2') && div.style.height === '0px') {
                var tag1 = '<table><tr><td class="td">Date First Available</td><td class="td2">18 June 2018</td></tr><tr><td class="td">Item part number</td><td class="td2">SVJG972080_1</td></tr><tr><td class="td">Color</td><td class="td2">White</td></tr><tr><td class="td">Material Type</td><td class="td2">velvet upper and rubber sole</td></tr><tr><td class="td">Shoes size</td><td class="td2">38</td></tr></table>';
                    div.innerHTML = tag1;
                    div.style.height = '180px';
              }else if (e.target === document.querySelector('.button3') && div.style.height === '0px') {
                var tag1 = '<div id="wrapper3" class="open1"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed efficitur ante eget lorem varius, ut lacinia leo finibus. Nam commodo luctus odio ac consectetur. Donec vel magna nec augue condimentum condimentum ut a neque. Mauris leo sem, tincidunt ac vulputate eget, ullamcorper vitae velit. Morbi a sem laoreet tellus bibendum iaculis non eu mauris. Nam ut interdum massa, ac lacinia velit. Praesent imperdiet fringilla interdum. </p></div>';
                    div.innerHTML = tag1;
                    div.style.height = '140px';
              }
           }
```

Comment: Can you describe what you hope to achieve by including `&& div.style.height === '0px'`  Is your hope to figure out if the div is empty? If so there are ways to achieve this but the way you are trying to do it will not work because it is checking for an explicitly set style property, not getting a computed height value of the element.

Comment: WillD. sorry for late reply I actually want the height to expand when I click on each text that i have so in if condition i used this to see if the height is 0px than it should execute the below height

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 && div.style.height === '0px'
```

To:

```
 && div.clientHeight == 0
```

This will access the browser's calculation of the element's height (excluding its borders) which is the result of all of the CSS and inner content calculations that determine the ultimate height of an element. Your initial code didn't work because you were asking to see the value of the the "height" inline style property (as in `<div style="height:200px">`).  Your div didn't have that property set to anything.

Comment: i tried this before but it didn't work. it does expand the layout but it does not toggle

Comment: I guess I am not sure why you need this "if" check at all? Have you tried omitting it entirely and adding `<div class="toggle-list" height="0px"></div>` in your HTML?

Comment: No not in HTML tag it's in CSS. sorry for that I'll try now

Comment: Sorry I meant <div class="toggle-list" style="height: 0px"></div>...  try that.

Comment: so i just want to toggle each text that should have different tags for each text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

use `offsetHeight` method

```
if (e.target === document.querySelector('.button1') && div.offsetHeight === 0) {
            var tag1 = 
           '<div id="wrapper1" class="open1">
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  Nam ut interdum massa, ac lacinia velit. Praesent imperdiet fringilla interdum.
                </p>
            </div>';
                div.innerHTML = tag1;
                div.offsetHeight = 160;
          }else if (e.target === document.querySelector('.button2') && div.offsetHeight ===  0) {
            var tag1 = '<table>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="td">Date First Available</td>
                              <td class="td2">18 June 2018</td> 
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="td">Item part number</td>
                              <td class="td2">SVJG972080_1</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td class="td">Color</td>
                               <td class="td2">White</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td class="td">Material Type</td>
                               <td class="td2">velvet upper and rubbersole</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td class="td">Shoes size</td>
                               <td class="td2">38</td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>';
                div.innerHTML = tag1;
                div.offsetHeight = 180;
          }else if (e.target === document.querySelector('.button3') && div.offsetHeight === 0) {
            var tag1 = '<div id="wrapper3" class="open1">
                          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent imperdiet fringilla interdum. 
                          </p>
                       </div>';
                div.innerHTML = tag1;
                div.offsetHeight = 140;
          }
```